# Django template: How to split SplitDateTimeWidget?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-widget

Can't figure out how to render `date` and `time` fields of `SplitDateTimeWidget` separately.

This renders both fields:

```
{{ form.datetime_field }}
```

But what if I want to use them on different places?

I tried:

```
{{ form.datetime_field_0 }}
<hr>
{{ form.datetime_field_1 }}
```

Which didn't render anything.

How can I access those fields separately?